# SerializedPropertyBindings NullReferenceException

Tags: unity, c#, ios, visual-studio, git

[image: Error image]

**Using:**

Unity 4.6.1 Pro

Visual Studio 2013 Pro, c#

Team Foundation Connected to git vc

Windows 7 Premium

Building 2D iOS app (2D set up)

**Details:**

Periodically, this error is occurring. There is no pattern to invoke this error so far.

I then found this on the official Unity forums: [Strange error showing up](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/426993/strange-error-showing-up.html)

But, I would like to avoid creating an entirely new project and re-importing everything, since it is getting to become a slightly large project. I do remember deleting an asset out of the file directory(not in unity), on accident, so this may be the issue. Is there any way to clean/wipe/fix this issue, w/o doing a fresh project and import?

I appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I don't know much about Unity, but here's a guess: Try re-creating an asset with the same name and deleting it again from the software, maybe that will un-block it.

Comment: You can't create assets with the same name, (1) will just append to the name

Comment: The link you've sent says that a possible cause of this error is if you delete an asset from the file explorer. It that what you've done? I would verify the integrity of all my assets though just to be sure.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I did do this, unfortunately a long time ago. Just tried your advice, no luck. I could delete all assets and re-import them from unity. I was trying to avoid this though because it is such a large project, with lots of prefabs, that connect to these assets. There must be a work around and this is what I am after

Comment: Sometimes in unity it helps to clean the "Library" folder.